# How to call 'docker swarm unlock' non-interactively?

Tags: docker, swarm

How can I call 'docker swarm unlock' non-interactively from a script?

Normally when you run the unlock command you get an interactive prompt like the following:

```
node $ docker swarm unlock
Please enter unlock key:
```

I've tried running the following:

```
node $ echo "SWMKEY-1-g8Kpx6C7xIIaabdcefghMLB5YYaf5OSLL4sA1234567" | docker swarm unlock
```

This does unlock my swarm but the command never returns.  It just hangs there.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_unlock/#description) it does not appear that there are any additional flags I can pass to the unlock command.

Comment: Have you tried building an expect script instead? Just have expect read the stdout and pass data into it automatically?

Comment: @Dockstar, thanks for the suggestion.  I had not tried an expect script but that would probably have worked.  As it turns out I had a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more investigation and testing.  I did not properly understand the problem I was seeing.

You **can** non-interactively unlock a docker swarm node using a command like the following:

```
node $ echo "SWMKEY-1-g8Kpx6C7xIIaabdcefghMLB5YYaf5OSLL4sA1234567" | docker swarm unlock
```

where SWMKEY-1-g8Kpx6C7xIIaabdcefghMLB5YYaf5OSLL4sA1234567 is the unlock key.

However, you need to run this on all nodes in your swarm cluster that are locked.  I had incorrectly assumed that you only needed to run the unlock command on a single node in the cluster and that would unlock all the nodes.

My scenario was as follows:

I have a 3 node cluster consisting of VMs node-1, node-2 and node-2 running in swarm mode.  I rebooted all 3 VMs.  I then ran the non-interactive unlock command on node-1 only and the command did not return.  Instead I need to run the unlock command on all nodes.

Also I should point out that the behavior of 'docker swarm unlock' is the same regardless of whether you are using it interactively or not.  When I had previously tested the interactive 'docker swarm unlock' I had been using a single node swarm cluster.